# Why does running a source code gets an installation error?

Tags: android

I have an source code of an Demo Application and I want to Run it using Android Studio. When I try to run it, an Error appears:
Installation failed due to: 'Invalid File: C:\Users\Caio\Documents\Projetos Teste\API-20211018T165829Z-001\API\mercuryapi-1.31.4.35\java\samples\android\RFIDReader\out\production\RFIDReader\RFIDReader.apk'

This Application uses a java lib to communicate with the App. I tried to remove RFIDReader.apk of its directory, but the error still continue. Does anyone knows the reason of it?